# JFreeChart Bar Graph Labels

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have made it possible for value labels to appear on top of the bar in JFreeChart. However, it would look better if the labels are inside the bars. How do I make this work? The image below shows what I wanted the graph to look like.

[image: Bar Graph with Label inside bar]

Answer (score 10):

I used the following code to make it work:

```
StackedBarRenderer renderer = new StackedBarRenderer(false);
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
chart.getCategoryPlot().setRenderer(renderer);`
```

Answer (score 5):

Just specify the desired [`ItemLabelPosition`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/ItemLabelPosition.html) in your [`CategoryItemLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/CategoryItemLabelGenerator.html). [`BarChartDemo3`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo3differentcolorswithinaseries.htm) is an example, shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).

Comment: Your example relies on the default `ItemLabelPosition` instances in [`AbstractRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#line.429).

Answer (score 5):

You can use **ItemLabelPosition** [DOC Here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/ItemLabelPosition.html)

```
renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12,TextAnchor.TOP_CENTER  ))
```

Output :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As fixing positions use **ItemLabelPosition**

```
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer(); 
CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator = new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}", NumberFormat.getInstance()); 

renderer.setItemLabelGenerator(generator); 
renderer.setItemLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12)); //just font change optional 
renderer.setItemLabelsVisible(true); 
renderer.setPositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER, - 0 / 2));
```

It will show your value in the Center of your bar. You can modify the position as per your requirements.