# displaying values on top of bar in jfree bar chart

Tags: jfreechart, bar-chart, jfreereport

I am using Jfreechart utility to create a Bar chart in Spring MVC. MY requirement is:

`i need to show corresponding value on top of the bar.`

How can i achieve this..please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JFreeChart Bar Graph Labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155294/jfreechart-bar-graph-labels)

Answer (score 2):

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) catPlot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator)
```

This method `setBaseItemLabelGenerator(CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator)` can be used to set corresponding values on the bar. [More info](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/AbstractCategoryItemRenderer.html#setBaseItemLabelGenerator%28org.jfree.chart.labels.CategoryItemLabelGenerator%29)