# JFreeChart 3D bar chart— can't increase Z axis depth

Tags: java, jfreechart

I try to increase *Z* axis size at my 3d bar chart. I use [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) at version 1.0.19, and can't find proper method to do this. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alter the *faux* depth, you can adjust the offset parameters in your `BarRenderer3D` constructor, for example:

```
BarRenderer3D r = new BarRenderer3D(
    3 * BarRenderer3D.DEFAULT_X_OFFSET / 2,
    3 * BarRenderer3D.DEFAULT_Y_OFFSET / 2);
categoryPlot.setRenderer(r);
```

[image]

To adjust the category label position and font size, use the approaches shown in [*JFreeChart Bar Graph Labels*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7155294/230513). See also [*Migration from JFreeChart 1.0.x*](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart#migration-from-jfreechart-10x) regarding 3D charts.

Comment: Tkank You very much. This is it what i need.